Adding search bar like "find and edit" (without edit) directly on my website
I created a search bar on my website, but it only shows me on which page the results are. It is not leading me to the exact place of the searched content.
I want a search function like it is on the chrome browser, where you search for specific words on a specific page. In Chrome its called: "search and edit". I want the same search function but without the "edit".
is there a way? I have no coding knowledge.
I was asking ChatGPT. It gave me different codes, but it never worked.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
